# No Windows7 entry on GRUB2's menu after installing Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, windows-7

I Installed Ubuntu 12.04  and after installation no Windows 7 entry shown.

Boot-Repair output : http://paste.ubuntu.com/1396793/

Answer (score 0):

Some Windows boot files are missing. Probably there was a separate Windows boot partition that was erased when you installed Ubuntu.

Solution:

1. Use a Windows7 disk this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader , until you get direct access to Windows
2. then use Boot-Repair's `Recommended Repair` to recover the GRUB menu

Answer (score -1):

"Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda"

So basically you installed the grub to the only place the windows Bootloader can resist. Not a very good Idea.

The (from a Usability Poihnt of view) easiest Solution imho is:

Reinstall Windows MBR like this:

You need: A Windows Installation or Recovery Medium

This restores the MasterBootRecord. Grub will be gone (or at least not useable anymore) only Windows boots up.

- boot from that Windows Disk
- select "Repair my Computer"
- select your Windows Installation
- select "Command Prompt"
- now execute following command each at a time:

`bootrec.exe /FixBoot`

`bootrec.exe /FixMbr`

Now reboot and install ubuntu again, but this time do NOT install grub directly to the sda mbr, but somewhere else.

Good luck, I recommend google and reading some articles about partitioning, double booting and stuff. It is worth the time, since it saves much in the future.

Comment: Installing GRUB somewhere other than sda seems like wrong advice. Installing to sda1 is only recommended when **chainloading** needs to be used. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing